# November Meetup - 2016 - Sitecore User Group Sri Lanka

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Date/Time (IST): Tuesday, November 29, 2016, 7:00 - 8:30 PM

Date/Time (UTC): Tuesday, November 29, 2016, 1:30 - 3:00 PM

Location: Colombo

RSVP: https://www.meetup.com/sugsrilanka/events/235421992/

November Meetup - 2016 - Sitecore User Group Sri Lanka

Agenda:

7:00 - 7:45 - Introduction to ASP.NET Core

7:45 - 8:30 - Introduction to UI and UX Engineering

8:30 - Networking